# Saving keyboard input to txt file with an Android app.

Tags: android, file, keyboard, save

I want to make an app to listen keyboard actions. My app will run in background and it will save every single keyboard action to a txt file. Is it possible to make it without editing onKey() method of Softkeyboard or Swiftkeyboard? Thanks.

Comment: may this helps : https://github.com/tomgersic/AndroidKeyLogger

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible for obvious privacy reasons.